# how can i see recurring payment details on my website?

Tags: ubercart

Currently i am using ubercart for recurring payment everything is working fine i can see status of mine recurring payment on paypal account

But how can i see recurring payment details on my website i have searched so many times on google but not got any relative article.

When i go to **/admin/store/orders/39/recurring** that page always shows blank details  .

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to see my memberships at `/admin/store/orders/recurring` (this is Drupal 6). From there I can edit the recurring fees and search based on a number of different properties.

Comment: will you please let me know the entire process which module you have used ,i have used commerce subscription with recurring module in drupal 7 after that i created product and added feature recurring for 1 day after checkout completion i go to  /admin/store/orders/39/recurring but its not showing under this tab

Comment: i think i am missing some configuration of module, i am using paypal wps for payment,role is also granting everything is working fine except recurring fee details, i am not able to conclude where i am missing while configuring module

Comment: @Vikram8888 `i have used commerce subscription with recurring module` is that a Drupal Commerce module? ... I thought you said you were using Ubercart...

Comment: yes i am using ubercart ,its so urgent for me to know the solution becoz i have to deliever my project within 2 days

Comment: @Vikram8888 there is a Drupal 6 tutorial [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/uc_recurring), I hope this helps.

Comment: @Vikram8888 Do you see anything at the `/admin/store/orders/recurring` page?

Comment: i concluded only credit card payment works with recurring payment but when i added Credit card (includes PayPal Website Payments Pro) payment gateway on review order page i am getting error like We were unable to process your credit card payment." Please verify your details and try again. If the problem persists, contact us to complete your order"

Comment: but when i implement Credit card (includes Test gateway) recurring payment is working fine i can see recurring payment details on my website,but i am not able to access with  Credit card (includes PayPal Website Payments Pro) getting error on review order page

Comment: I don't think that PayPal Website Payments Pro supports recurring payments. It could be that this is what's causing the discrepancy.